# How to click a particular tab using Angular and how to include Angular UI in the code

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using Angular UI Bootstrap http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/. I have two questions:

1. I followed the example given at *angular-ui.github.io*, there they use

   ```
   <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js">
   ```

   but I don't want to use the CDN so I downloaded Angular UI and added it to my project. How to include it into my code? 
   I did add
   `['ui.bootstrap']` to my `angular.module`, but it's not working until I add the above script code.
2. I'm using `<tabset>` to create two tabs, contacts and group. For
   example, a user is in the Group tab, he wants to add members to an existing group, so if he clicks the Add Member button, I want to navigate to the Contacts tab automatically.

   I thought of using `document.getElementByTagName()` inside my
   controller. Will it work? And what is the Angular way to click
   something programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question #1:

```
<script src="folder_of_js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
```

Question #2:

You don't use `document.getElementByTagName()` with AngularJS, if you want to navigate to a tab while you are in another tab's content, an example might be the following:

```
<tabset>
   <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}">
      {{tab.content}}
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="tabs[2].active = true">Select third tab</button>
   </tab>
</tabset>
```

As you can also see in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7XvmsjAZ1DrA0K4F6kiw?p=preview), I added a button that navigates to the third tab whenever you click it.

Comment: iam having it in side BootstrapMaster folder inside that lots of folders are there like demos ,src,template,docs and misc.so  where  i can find ui-bootsrtap-tpls-0.0.10.0.js

Comment: where is your `index.html`? this should be your root, then any folder inner than this should go to the source. For example, index.html is in  `app/` and bootstrap is in `app/one/two/three` then your script src should look like: `<script src="one/two/three/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

The script file is probably not loaded by the browser. You have to add a script tag pointing to where the file is in your project. For example, if the script is placed in the folder `/scripts/lib/`:

```
<script src="/scripts/lib/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js" />
```

One of the golder rules of AngularJS is to never, for any reason, referrence the DOM (i.e. an HTML element) from a controller. So while document.getElementByTagName() will *technically* work, I would advice against it.

In angular, you really don't click things programmatically. The common way is to bind something in your HTML to a variable in the `$scope`, either by curly brackets (`{{someVariable}}`), or by directives such as `ng-class`, `ng-bind` etc. Then you change that variable in `$scope`, and the HTML changes to reflect that. Is there a variable in `$scope` which determines which tab is open? If so, you can just change that variable, and it should work automagically.

Comment: thanks for reply. you mean $scope.tabs what  i should do with that and can you give some example code.

Comment: Look at @anvarik 's answer, he's got you covered :)